# Is there a way to shift pandas data frame first row only one cell to the right?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meoYT.png)

i'm trying to shift the first row only by one cell to the right so the dates start under number 1 column,
also i'm trying to remove the tailing '\n' by doing this but its not working, any help please?

```
income_df2 = income_df2.replace('[\$,)]','', regex=True )\
                     .replace( '[(]','-', regex=True)\
                     .replace( '', 'NaN', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this shift he first row of a dataframe to the right one column.  Use `iloc` to select this row  all columns which returns a pd.Series, then use `shift` to shift the values of this series one position and assign this newly shifted series back to the first row of the dataframe.

```
df.iloc[0, :] = df.iloc[0, :].shift()
```

MCVE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[*'ABCD']+[np.nan],[1,2,3,4,5],[5,6,7,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]])

df
# Input DataFrame
#    0   1   2   3     4
# 0   A   B   C   D   NaN
# 1   1   2   3   4   5.0
# 2   5   6   7   9  10.0
# 3  11  12  13  14  15.0


df.iloc[0, :] = df.iloc[0, :].shift()

df
# Output DataFrame
#      0   1   2   3   4
# 0  NaN   A   B   C   D
# 1    1   2   3   4   5
# 2    5   6   7   9  10
# 3   11  12  13  14  15
```